# Remove the 'head' directory from a file path

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

In .NET (VB or C#) Does anyone know a simple way to remove the 'head' directory from a file path String, meaning if I have path that looks something like this: `Directory1/Directory2/Directory3`I want to get `Directory2/Directory3` back. I know there are some ways to do it, like split it into an array, and then starting with the second element concatenate it all back, I just feel like that, that's its an extremely inefficient way of doing it and was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: What does efficiency have to do with anything? Are you really going to call this so often that you're worried about a few extra microseconds?

Comment: An "extremely inefficient" way would be writing this out to a server through a dial-up connection then reading it back. One two-element temporary array won't even register.

Comment: **Correctness** almost always trumps efficient... and in this case look at System.IO.Path to help ensure correctness.

Comment: If you're dealing with files on disk, a bit of string parsing is going to be the smallest of your performance problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you're looking for. If you know that things are in the form `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4...`, then you can just look for the first `/` and take everything after that:

```
string dir = "dir1/dir2/dir3";
var pos = dir.IndexOf('/');
if (pos != -1)
{
    result = dir.Substring(pos+1);
}
```

If you can also accept full path names of the form `c:\dir\dir\file.ext` or `\\server\dir\dir\file.ext`, then you'll probably want to make sure that you make any relative paths into full paths first. Then use the methods in the `System.IO.Path` class to extract the drive or server names before using something like the `IndexOf` trick above.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class. It has a number of useful methods for this kind of thing.

For example, you might use it's `GetPathRoot()` method as part of a call to String.Replace() like so:

```
public string RemoveHead(string path)
{
    return path.Replace(Path.GetPathRoot(path), "");
}
```

I don't have Visual Studio handy, so that likely needs some tweaks to account for separator characters or Drive letters, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: But `GetPathRoot` is going to return an empty string for `directory1\directory2\directory3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want correctness and efficiency,

```
string path=@"dir1/dir2/dir3";
path=path.Substring(path.IndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)+1);
```

only 1 new string is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Removes head.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to drop head.</param>
    /// <param name="retainSeparator">If to retain separator before next folder when deleting head.</param>
    /// <returns>New path.</returns>
    public static string GetPathWithoutHead (string path, bool retainSeparator = false)
    {
        if (path == null) 
        {
            return path;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (path)) 
        {
             throw new ArgumentException(path, "The path is not of a legal form.");
        }

        var root = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot (path);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(root) && !StartsWithAny(root,System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
        {               
            return path.Remove(0,root.Length);
        }

        var sep = path.IndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        var altSep = path.IndexOf(System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
        var pos = MaxPositiveOrMinusOne (sep, altSep);
        if (pos == -1)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (pos == 0) 
        {
            return GetPathWithoutHead(path.Substring(pos+1), retainSeparator);
        }

        var eatSeparator = !retainSeparator ? 1 : 0;
        return path.Substring(pos+eatSeparator);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Startses the with.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns><c>true</c>, if with was startsed, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
    /// <param name="val">Value.</param>
    /// <param name="maxLength">Max length.</param>
    /// <param name="chars">Chars.</param>
    private static bool StartsWithAny(string value, params char[] chars)
    {
        foreach (var c in chars) 
        {
            if (value[0] == c) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maxs the positive or minus one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The positive or minus one.</returns>
    /// <param name="val1">Val1.</param>
    /// <param name="val2">Val2.</param>
    private static int MaxPositiveOrMinusOne(int val1, int val2)
    {
        if (val1 < 0 && val2 < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return Math.Max(val1,val2: val2);
    }
```

[Several unit tests are here](https://gitlab.com/dzmitry-lahoda/clr/blob/master/bcl/extensions/PathExtensionsTests.cs)